# def __str__ on model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking to return a str on this model that is equal to industry name + risk level (i.e. Low)

```
RISKLEVEL = (
    (0, "Low"),
    (1, "Medium"),
    (2, "High"),
    )

class IndustryIndex(models.Model):
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    risk = models.IntegerField(choices=RISKLEVEL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.industry + self.page
```

I know that my syntax on the line under `def __str__(self):` isn't correct. Do you know what it should be? Also, self.page only seems to return the integer, but I'm interested in returning the description (i.e. 'High').

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_risk_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{}-{}'.format(self.industry, self.get_risk_display())
```

Comment: Thanks neverwalkaloner. I can always rely on you for great advice!!

Comment: @JasonHoward you are welcome. Also you can use string formatting instead of concatenation with `+` sign.